# jQuery Global Settings for Hides?

Tags: jquery

I have a request - not sure if it's possible.

Throughout my application, when I call the `hide()` method on an element, I would like it to default to `hide("fade", 200)` without having to type the `"fade", 200` each time.

Is there a "global" setting I can set to accomplish this? Sort of like the the `ajaxSetup()` feature?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to create your custom plugin for this , call it as fadeHide or some other name , as hide is jquery function

```
(function($){

  $.fn.fadeHide= function(options) {

    this.hide("fade",200);

  };

});
```

Now you can call this plugin as

$`('div').fadeHide();`

Answer (score 8):

You can create your own fade function instead, call it say `myFade`:

```
$.fn.myFade = function () {
    this.hide("fade", 200);
};
$('div').myFade();
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/sT4AV/)**

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe you can create a default but you can always try to create a custom js function to handle it. You might try to create a utility js that is distributed across your site like this...

```
jqueryOverride = {
    hide: function(element) {
        $(element).hide("fade", 200)
    }
}
```

Comment: Have a look at the other answers here - they show how to extend jQuery's functionality the proper way.